# delphi: how to to store TCustomFrames and records in one list

Tags: list, delphi, record, tframe

I am using a `TObjectList<TCustomFrame>` to store `TCustomFrames`. Now i want to store some more information regarding to the `TCustomFrame` in the same list. A `record` would be nice.

Which delphi class would you prefer to store `TCustomFrames` and `records` in the same list?

The `TCustomFrames` and `records` will be added at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a single record to hold all the information:

```
type 
  TFrameInfo = record
    Frame: TCustomFrame;
    Foo: string;
    Bar: Integer;
  end;
```

Hold that in a `TList<TFrameInfo>`.

I note that you were using `TObjectList<T>` rather than `TList<T>`. The only good reason for doing that would be if you were setting `OwnsObjects` to `True`. But that seems unlikely since I doubt that the list is really in charge of the lifetime of your GUI objects. As a note for the future, if you find yourself  using `TObjectList<T>` with `OwnsObjects` set to `False` then you may as well switch to `TList<T>`.

Now, in case you do need the list to control the lifetime then you'd be best using a class rather than a record for `TFrameInfo`.

```
type 
  TFrameInfo = class
  private
    FFrame: TCustomFrame;
    FFoo: string;
    FBar: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(AFrame: TCustomFrame; AFoo: string; ABar: Integer);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Frame: TCustomFrame read FFrame;
    // etc.
  end;

  constructor TFrameInfo.Create(AFrame: TCustomFrame; AFoo: string; ABar: Integer);
  begin
    inherited Create;
    FFrame := AFrame;
    // etc.
  end;

  destructor TFrameInfo.Destroy; 
  begin
    FFrame.Free;
    inherited;
  end;
```

And then hold this in a `TObjectList<TFrameInfo>` with `OwnsObjects` set to `True`.